# Matching emails separated by commas in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I want to match emails separated by a comma like this :

```
'a@a.com, b@b.com, c@c.com'
```

I'm would like to reuse the regex defined in the Devise gem :

```
 /\A[^@\s]+@([^@\s]+\.)+[^@\s]+\z/
```

I **know** that I won't be [RFC2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822) compliant but I don't care because I only need a very simple email validation.

My attempt to match the emails separated by commas is the following :

```
/\A(([^@\s]+@([^@\s]+\.)+[^@\s]+),)*\s([^@\s]+@([^@\s]+\.)+[^@\s]+)\z/
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     everything like 'a@a.com,'   spaces   last element 'c@c.com'
     many times
```

Unfortunately this is not working as expected. It is matching string like this (note the trailing comma) :

```
a@a.com, b@b.com, c@c.com,
```

Could someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only matching the space after the last comma, move the `\s` to the group that is repeating. Also as Platinum Azure mentioned `[^@\s]` includes commas you can avoid this by changing it to `[^@\s,]`

```
/\A(([^@\s]+@([^@\s]+\.)+[^@\s,]+),\s)*([^@\s]+@([^@\s,]+\.)+[^@\s,]+)\z/
```

Comment: In addition, the final `[^@\s]+` would include commas, which explains the specific example given by the OP.

Comment: Thanks, I somehow missed that part of the question.